# Jquery Sliding Form Mobile Devices Configuration

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

i built a form based on this (http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FancySlidingForm/) one for my website. It's working great on my pc and did the necessary adjustments on websites like responsinator.com to make it responsive for tablets, smartphones, etc.
However, mainly on the horizontal parts of ipads and smartphones, the labels and inputs of the second, third and next tabs are completely sided, not centered and out of screen.

I read something here about Jquery Mobile. I'm not using any of that, just this one:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Should i? or even jquery mobile will not fix my problem?

Thanks!

The Jquery Function that does the sliding part:

```
$(function() {
/*
number of fieldsets
*/
var fieldsetCount = $('#formElem').children().length;

/*
current position of fieldset / navigation link
*/
var current     = 1;

/*
sum and save the widths of each one of the fieldsets
set the final sum as the total width of the steps element
*/
var stepsWidth  = 0;
var widths      = new Array();
$('#steps .step').each(function(i){
    var $step       = $(this);
    widths[i]       = stepsWidth;
    stepsWidth      += $step.width();
});
$('#steps').width(stepsWidth);

/*
to avoid problems in IE, focus the first input of the form
*/
$('#formElem').children(':first').find(':input:first').focus(); 

/*
show the navigation bar
*/
$('#navigation_form').show();

/*
when clicking on a navigation link 
the form slides to the corresponding fieldset
*/
$('#navigation_form a').bind('click',function(e){
    var $this   = $(this);
    var prev    = current;
    $this.closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected');
    $this.parent().addClass('selected');
    /*
    we store the position of the link
    in the current variable 
    */
    current = $this.parent().index() + 1;
    /*
    animate / slide to the next or to the corresponding
    fieldset. The order of the links in the navigation
    is the order of the fieldsets.
    Also, after sliding, we trigger the focus on the first 
    input element of the new fieldset
    If we clicked on the last link (confirmation), then we validate
    all the fieldsets, otherwise we validate the previous one
    before the form slided
    */
    $('#steps').stop().animate({
        marginLeft: '-' + widths[current-1] + 'px'
    },500,function(){
        if(current == fieldsetCount)
            validateSteps();
        else
            validateStep(prev);
        $('#formElem').children(':nth-child('+ parseInt(current) +')').find(':input:first').focus();    
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});

/*
clicking on the tab (on the last input of each fieldset), makes the form
slide to the next step
*/


$('#formElem > fieldset').each(function(){
    var $fieldset = $(this);
    $fieldset.children(':last').find(':input').keydown(function(e){
        if (e.which == 9){
            $('#navigation_form li:nth-child(' + (parseInt(current)+1) + ') a').click();
            /* force the blur for validation */
            $(this).blur();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});

/*
validates errors on all the fieldsets
records if the Form has errors in $('#formElem').data()
*/
function validateSteps(){
    var FormErrors = false;
    for(var i = 1; i < fieldsetCount; ++i){
        var error = validateStep(i);
        if(error == -1)
            FormErrors = true;
    }
    $('#formElem').data('errors',FormErrors);   
}



/*
validates one fieldset
and returns -1 if errors found, or 1 if not
*/
function validateStep(step){
    if(step == fieldsetCount) return;

    var error = 1;
    var hasError = false;
    $('#formElem').children(':nth-child('+ parseInt(step) +')').find(':input:not(button)').each(function(){
        var $this       = $(this);
        var valueLength = jQuery.trim($this.val()).length;

    if(($this.attr('id')!='info_adicional') && ($this.attr('id')!='curriculum_vitae')) {
        if(valueLength == ''){
            hasError = true;
            //$this.css('background-color','#FFEDEF');
        }
    }
        //else
            //$this.css('background-color','#A8FC9C');  /* Campo preenchido */
    });
    var $link = $('#navigation_form li:nth-child(' + parseInt(step) + ') a');
    $link.parent().find('.error,.checked').remove();

    var valclass = 'checked';
    if(hasError){
        error = -1;
        valclass = 'error';
    }
    $('<span class="'+valclass+'"></span>').insertAfter($link);

    return error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use js for mobile

http://jquerymobile.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

If the only problem is your labels being outpositioned, you may want to use [CSS Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to adjust your CSS per device.

There is quite some art to make CSS look good for both, desktop and mobile browsers :)

You might also want to check these links:

1. http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html
2. http://www.metaltoad.com/sites/default/files/Responsive-Widths_0.png
3. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/30/designing-for-android/

P.S.: jQuery Mobile uses its own (and rather complex) CSS and JavaScript that is tailored for mobile usage... it's not a drop-in replacement for your custom CSS

Comment: Zathrus i used media queries to make the code responsive. The problem is on the sliding effect. The firs tab is good, but when i change to the second or third, the new fields appear part on the screen and the other part outside.

Comment: in that case, you probably need to debug and correct the CSS for those tabs... since you did not provide a working code, we cannot help you further, sorry

Comment: But then it's a css problem right? Nothing to do with the jquery function correct?

Comment: if it's a display problem, it's a CSS thing... unless the JavaScript adjusts that CSS manually (you should be able to see that with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/))

Comment: i posted above the jquery function that does the slide. Could you please take a look and tell me if it's a problem from there. Because if not then it's as you say, a css problem.

Comment: it seems that that code DOES adjust style of some elements... it's best to use Firebug and debug that way, or make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) page with some working code example